# how to parse these types of dynamic links

Tags: javascript, php

i have some strange question. i know when i visit any folder of site and in that folder if we have index.php then the xyz.com/folder_name will display contents of that folder if index.php file is there.

i just came across one site here

https://santabanta.pushpaddy.com/

when u will load u can see in network tab that they are loading several links as usual but i did not understand this particular link. how this link is being processed.

https://santabanta.pushpaddy.com/check/emj_F9FghmI:APA91bHsomenoandtextHn2qOPwvs-Jti-pAR1vYDsomenoandtextx2lWwyyYP-Ez1kQsomenoandtextl94nQdmOZEOGYVnA-cVhum6YrN0ZFLUIqu-PmGXMecysomenoandtextc9vvmuyxQ

after check you can see that its generated dynamically and how the server will process these data??

defenitely nothing is there in index.php under check folder. so how it is working. if you will open that link directly it will give that 404 error but when i reload that page

https://santabanta.pushpaddy.com/

it fetches content from check link with 200 code means all are fine.

i know it looks like silly question but i really want to learn this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding this is a token(Like [JWT](https://jwt.io/)) directly attache to url so that if you open url the server side code will read token and convert the token from encrypted to decrypted and use this information to perform further logic.

Comment: i was knowing something basic will be there which i dont know as of now. thanks for pointing out in right direction. i am trying to understanfd jwt

Comment: can u suggest some tutorial where i can learn how to parse these types of url in php. i tried php explode but it wont work becasue server is expecting that as folder